# No funciona mi metodo math random

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un problema, estaba tratando de resolver un problema en donde me piden calcular el consumo anual de agua de un piso de un departamento, el departamento tiene 8 pisos de 4 casas cada piso, creé la matriz donde las filas son los meses del año, y las columnas son las casas (casa 1, casa 2,etc). Al iniciar la consola, al elegir la opción 1 que es la que llevo (las otras 2 opciones no las tomen en cuenta), no me llena aleatoriamente la matriz como la he indicado, pues me arroja siempre que el consumo es 0, agradecería si la pudieran revisar y ver donde esta el error

```
import java.util.*;


public class JavaApplication1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] consumo = new int[11][31];
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    llenar(consumo);  
    int opcn;
    System.out.println("1.- Consumo anual de un piso");
    System.out.println("2.- Consumo anual de cada piso");
    System.out.println("3.- Mes de mayor consumo");
    opcn = leer.nextInt();
    switch(opcn){
    case 1: conspiso(consumo); break;


    }
    }

    public static int[][] llenar (int [][]consumo){

    for (int x=0; x < consumo.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < consumo.length; y++)
    consumo[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;//Suponiendo que cada departamento 
    no consume más de 20m3 por mes
    }
    return consumo;
    }


     public static void conspiso (int consumo[][]){
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Que piso desea buscar su consumo anual? 1-8");
        int piso = leer.nextInt();
        if(piso >8 || piso < 1){
        System.out.println("Piso no valido, ingrese nuevamente");
        conspiso(consumo);
        }
        int suma =0;
        switch(piso){

        case 1:  
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=0; y==3; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 1 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 2: 
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=4; y==7; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];

            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 2 es "+suma+"m3");     
            break;
        case 3: 
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=8; y==11; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 3 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 4:
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=12; y==15; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 4 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 5: 
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=16; y==19; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 5 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 6: 
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=20; y==23; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 6 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 7: 
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=24; y==27; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 7 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
        case 8:
            for(int x=0; x==11;x++){
            for(int y=28; y==31; y++){
            suma = suma+ consumo[x][y];
            }
            }
            System.out.println("El consumo anual en el piso 8 es "+suma+"m3");
            break;
}
}         
}
```

Comment: La probabilidad de que un programador culpe a una función del API de Java de un error es inversamente proporcional a su experiencia. Te aseguro que Math.random funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error al completar la matriz, si `x` e `y` los utilizas para recorrer los indices de la primera y segunda dimension respectivamente, entonces `y` debe recorrer hasta `consumo[x].length`:

```
public static int[][] llenar (int [][]consumo){

    for (int x=0; x < consumo.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < consumo[x].length; y++)
            consumo[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;//Suponiendo que cada departamento no consume más de 20m3 por mes
    }
    return consumo;
}
```

Comment: Lo corregí como mencionas, igualmente me sigue arrojando 0 en consola

Comment: @Pablo Lozano encontro tu otro error en los bucles for, mira su respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Tienes muchos errores en tus bucles:

En el método llenar:

```
public static int[][] llenar (int [][]consumo){

  for (int x=0; x < consumo.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < consumo.length; y++) //aqui debería ser consumo[x].length
      consumo[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;
  }
  return consumo;
}
```

En cada uno de tus `case`:

```
 for(int x=0; x==11;x++){ //X no es 11, por lo que no se ejecuta el bucle
     for(int y=8; y==11; y++){ //Y no es 11, por lo que no se ejecuta el bucle
```

deberían ser así:

```
 for(int x=0; x<11;x++){
    for(int y=8; y<11; y++){
```

Comment: ok en ese caso lo corregí hasta x<12 porque quiero que recorra hasta el 11, y la consola me mandó esto: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Comment: Los indices en arreglos comienzan en 0, si tu arreglo es de largo 11 el ultimo indice es el 10.